# Magento 2 : How to get store contact number and email address

Tags: magento2

I want to display my magento 2 store contact detail & mail address in the frontend. How to get store contact and email address in magento 2 and display it in **header.phtml** file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following code worked for me.

```
<?php

namespace Addpeople\Websettings\Block;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class Footerlink extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
// protected $flHelper;
protected $_urlInterface;
protected $scopeConfig;


public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface,
    ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    // \Addpeople\Websettings\Helper\Footerlink $myModuleHelper,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    // $this->_flHelper = $myModuleHelper;
    $this->_urlInterface = $urlInterface;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;

}
public function getPhoneNumber()
{

    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('general/store_information/phone',ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);

}

public function getEmailUs()
{
    // @see /magento/module-email/etc/config.xml for various emails 
    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('trans_email/ident_general/email',ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);

}

public function getOpeningHours()
{

    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('general/store_information/hours',ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);

}

public function getPostcode()
{

    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('general/store_information/postcode',ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);

}

public function getCity()
{

    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('general/store_information/city',ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);

}

public function getRegionId()
{

    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('general/store_information/region_id',ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);

}

public function getStreetLine1()
{
    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('general/store_information/street_line1',ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);

}

public function getStreetLine2()
{
    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('general/store_information/street_line2',ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);

}

 }
```

Include the block in the **default.xml** by adding the following code

```
<referenceContainer name="footer">
   <block class="Addpeople\Websettings\Block\Footerlink" name="footerlink" after="footerlogo" template="footerlink.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Please add the following code in **footerlink.phtml**

```
<address>
    <span class="displayBlock street-address-1"><?php echo $block->getStreetLine1(); ?></span>
    <span class="displayBlock street-address-2"><?php echo $block->getStreetLine2(); ?></span>
    <span class="displayBlock city"><?php echo $block->getCity();?></span>
    <span class="displayBlock postcode"><?php echo $block->getPostcode();?></span>
    <span class="displayBlock region"><?php echo $block->getRegionId(); ?></span>
</address>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add any information to header without updating manually in .phtml file. Please follow below step.

1) Create static block and added content as you want to display in header

> admin login >> content >> blocks add new block.

2) Create new widget

> admin login >> content >> widget add new.

Select "cms static block" from type drop down >> select your theme >> add title >> select store >> click to "add layout update" button >>select design on all pages from drop down >> select page header from container dropdown and last >> click on left widget option and select your block which you want to display in header and Save this widget.

Note: clear cache before review this in front-end.

I hope this will help you.
Please let me know if you have any question and query.

Comment: Thanks for your replay Nits. But i was asking the store information which we can store inside Store>Configuration>genral> Store Email Address and Contact. I saved the information in backend but how i can render this information (contact and email address) in my phtml file. Thanks and hope you understand what i am asking..:)